# AWS SQS - move unconsumed message to the dead letter queue

Tags: amazon-sqs

I am using AWS SQS with dead letter queues.

I can easily insert messages to the dead letter queue if I consume them, but I want messages that weren't consumed for like a hour to be moved to the dead letter queue automatically.

Is this possible?
Am I missing a configuration option?

Regards,
Ido

Comment: Dead letter queue works on receive count and if that doesnt change the message will not be moved to dead letter queue. So, it cant be possible to move the message to dead letter queue. If you provide more detail about your problem, then I can suggest you something else like scale up or cloud watch to find out 'why the message didnt move' or scale up to process the message if there are not getting processed.

Answer (score 5):

Dead letter queues are not designed for this purpose; they specifically handle the case where a message can be successfully *received*, but cannot be *processed* successfully ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html#sqs-dead-letter-queues-when-to-use)). So in short, this is not currently possible. Alternatively, you could increase the message retention time so that the messages stay for longer on the queue giving your a consumer a chance to start listening again.

Hope that helps :)